# Question being down voted

Tags: discussion

I had posted a question on Stack Overflow and there were people who replied and gave me their solutions as well.

I even asked them if there was any other solution and was waiting for the reply. After a few minutes I my question started to get downvoted.

Just because someone doesn't understand a question, how can downvote me? If my question was unclear to them they could add a comment.

Can someone help me with this?

I am really getting worried when I am posting a new question now and even depressed with this.

Comment: The string "-ve" is not a word in the English language.

Comment: Downvote just means that the question is badly phrased and/or out of the sites scope. [Tasty faq link](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Show us what question you're talking about and we might have some suggestions on how to improve it. I'm assuming you're [referring to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893761/update-query-giving-insert-error)?

Comment: It seems like your problem is bad grammar. People tend to downvote it as non-serious.

Comment: Downvote button tooltip say (emphasis mine) "This question does not show any resaearch effort; it is **unclear** or not useful". If your question is not asked clearly, a downvote is appropriate (although if that is the reason for the downvote, the voter should reverse the vote once you have edited/improved the question)

Comment: @Bart - If the OP did refer to that question, then this question in meta may as well be closed, since the OP deleted the question to which you linked.

Comment: *If my question was unclear to them they could add a comment.* True, if there weren't such thing as [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). (I've not read your posts; just responding to the general statement.)

Comment: @helpme - helpus to helpyou!

Comment: I upvoted *this* question to encourage you in your quest for improvement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893761/update-query-giving-insert-error) is (/was) very unclear.

Add more details:

- The schema (partial if necessary) of your table
- Exactly what columns have unique indexes
- **The exact query that is failing**, and why it is failing.

You're creating duplicates in your table - that's not allowed. But no-one can help you if we don't know exactly how you're creating those duplicates, except with wild guesses or potentially dangerous/drastic suggestions (like dropping the constraints temporarily).

Explaining what you're trying to do could also help giving you a good answer. Is this a one-shot data fixup that you're doing while the application is offline (i.e. no concurrent users), normal (periodic) maintenance, normal application code? etc.

Be careful with vocabulary too:

> "I'm trying to update a table, but I am getting an insert error"

Update and insert are distinct things in SQL. Just that first sentence will confuse people about what you're trying to do. Be precise. Perfect grammar/English is not expected, but do try to use the right technical terms.
If you're not comfortable with english, add more "pictures", code, diagrams, whatever it takes to be sure people can understand exactly what you're talking about.

In short, people need to know what you're doing, and what you're doing it on, if you want relevant answers. Your question was not precise enough in its description of the situation and the problem.

Comment: Being new to a subject.. i cannot understand what the person is expecting.. i can only say what i understand or i think the problem is.. if i exactly knew what my problem was i would never post it .. rather find a solution myself... :(:( 

I cannot give the exact stored procedure as there are 52 columns in it and it looks weird i am going out all my company's database!

I am not trying to be rude... but i am worried i might be banned from positing in it anymore which make me depressed!!

Comment: The reproduce your issue on a dummy database with 3-4 column table, and post about that. Benefit of doing this: your question will be more useful generally, _and_ you might solve your issue while trying to reproduce it. People reading questions on SO are there to help. If your problem isn't expressed clearly, we can't. That's frustrating. Making your problem simpler will both help you and the people who can help. So narrow it down.

Comment: Downvoting isn't personal or critical. Remember, this is a site where people give up their time, for free, to help others. When a question doesn't give enough information for *anyone* to help, we downvote it to save other people time.

Comment: @ david and @mat thanks for your replies !!